# Calling method from another class, getting error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bluej

I'm getting an error calling a method from another class. I am in class **StockManager** and am wanting to call **toString** method in class **Product**.

But I'm getting error: *Constructor Product in class Product cannot be applied to given types: required: int.java.lang.String; found:no arguments; reason:actual and format argument lists differ in length*

BTW I'm using BlueJ.

Please note printProductDetails() method below. That is what I am trying to write.

Here is all of what I have got in StockManager class. I'm trying to print out details of toString in Product class in printProductDetails() method below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Manage the stock in a business.
* The stock is described by zero or more Products.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class StockManager
{
// A list of the products.
private ArrayList<Product> stock;

/**
 * Initialise the stock manager.
 */
public StockManager()
{
    stock = new ArrayList<Product>();
}

/**
 * Add a product to the list.
 * @param item The item to be added.
 */
public void addProduct(Product item)
{
    stock.add(item);
}

/**
 * Receive a delivery of a particular product.
 * Increase the quantity of the product by the given amount.
 * @param id The ID of the product.
 * @param amount The amount to increase the quantity by.
 */
public void delivery(int id, int amount)
{

}

/**
 * Try to find a product in the stock with the given id.
 * @return The identified product, or null if there is none
 *         with a matching ID.
 */
public Product findProduct(int id)
{
    return null;
}

/**
 * Locate a product with the given ID, and return how
 * many of this item are in stock. If the ID does not
 * match any product, return zero.
 * @param id The ID of the product.
 * @return The quantity of the given product in stock.
 */
public int numberInStock(int id)
{
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Print details of all the products.
 */
public void printProductDetails()
{
    Product string = new Product();
    string.toString(); {
                    System.out.println("Attempt to restock " +
                           name +
                           " with a non-positive amount: " +
                           amount);
                        }

}
}
```

Specific help in how to solve this and some reasons for the suggestions would be appreciated Thank you.

Product Class:

```
/**
 * Model some details of a product sold by a company.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */
public class Product
{
// An identifying number for this product.
private int id;
// The name of this product.
private String name;
// The quantity of this product in stock.
private int quantity;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Product.
 * The initial stock quantity is zero.
 * @param id The product's identifying number.
 * @param name The product's name.
 */
public Product(int id, String name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    quantity = 0;
}

/**
 * @return The product's id.
 */
public int getID()
{
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return The product's name.
 */
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return The quantity in stock.
 */
public int getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}

/**
 * @return The id, name and quantity in stock.
 */
public String toString()
{
    return id + ": " +
           name +
           " stock level: " + quantity;
}

/**
 * Restock with the given amount of this product.
 * The current quantity is incremented by the given amount.
 * @param amount The number of new items added to the stock.
 *               This must be greater than zero.
 */
public void increaseQuantity(int amount)
{
    if(amount > 0) {
        quantity += amount;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Attempt to restock " +
                           name +
                           " with a non-positive amount: " +
                           amount);
    }
}

/**
 * Sell one of these products.
 * An error is reported if there appears to be no stock.
 */
public void sellOne()
{
    if(quantity > 0) {
        quantity--;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(
            "Attempt to sell an out of stock item: " + name);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show us more code.  This won't compile as-is so we can't easily tell what the real problem is.

Comment: show us the Product class

Comment: The error message contains the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `{ ... }` block there!

Comment: Is there a default constructor in Product class?

Comment: Why are you constructing a product in the first place. Shouldn't the method implement what its javadoc says? (hint: it should).

Comment: I don't understand why these questions aren't closed as too localized.... it seems obvious here that the code in `printProductDetails` was cargo-culted from the provided `Product` class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the `printProductDetails` method print all products in `stock`? That is what the documentation says:

> - Print details of all the products.

So my guess is that you need to actually iterate your `stock` and not try to construct a `Product`.

```
public void printProductDetails() {
    for (Product product:stock) {
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I am required to call the toString. So I don't think your method will work

Comment: @Nick Java will call `toString` implicitly. You could simply call it explicitly if you like.

Comment: Hi Tim, Please explain what your code above is doing. Please explain in words so I can better understand.

Comment: @Nick, I think it is fairly evident what occurs here. If you simply copy/paste this into your program, it will work as intended. When you submit it to your instructor, they will find it suspicious (again, works as intended). I think the remainder of this exercise is to leave it to you, as the student, to research and determine why this code works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a default constructor in Product class (without arguments), or pass int id, String name when you are getting a Product instance:

```
// ...
Product string = new Product(1, "test value");
string.toString();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question this is what I think.

You need to override `toString()` in your `Product class`. Add this method in your `Product class`

```
public String toString()
{
     String str = "\n******Product ******\n"+
                   "Name :"+this.name+
                   "\nType :"+this.type;
    return str;
}
```

You can print your product bye using `System.out.println(product)` where `product` is instance of `Product class`